# Java and simple json

Tags: java, json

I am trying to get from a json username this is the json

```
[{"user_id":"1","username":"THEUSERNAME","count300":"0","count100":"0","count50":"0","playcount":"0","ranked_score":"0","total_score":"0","pp_rank":"0","level":"0","pp_raw":"0","accuracy":"0","count_rank_ss":"0","count_rank_s":"0","count_rank_a":"0","country":"0","events":[]}]
```

My code is

```
URL url = new URL("url");
        URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) b.append(line);
        String text = b.toString();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(text);
        String username = (String) jsonObject.get("username");
        System.out.println(username);
```

And the error i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
at eu.dpp.ircbot.Ircbot.main(Ircbot.java:80)
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? Do you know the JSON format?

Comment: Read this how to: http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the [] around your original string. This indicates that it's a JSONArray and not a JSONObject, which is exactly what the exception you get tells you. For the JSON specs, see http://json.org/

The actual object is surrounded with {}, you may be confused because you only have 1 object inside the array. But you still have to treat the string as an array and then iterate over the objects in it.